# Why mistake appears during render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using [react-highcharts](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) in my project. I want to generat chart-component dynamicaly and change their number according to user's choice. I wrote component and function which gets data and makes array of highcharts component and returns them:

```
export default class ContentChartItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }

        this.config = {}

    render() {
        let { process_data } = this.props;
        let config = this.config;

        return (
            <div className="column">
                {typeof process_data == "undefined" ? " "
                    :
                    <div className="ui segment">
                        {this.getChartItemsList}
                        <div className="ui button tiny fluid sidenav4">
                            Info
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    getChartItemsList = () => {
        let config = this.config;
        let { process_data } = this.props;
        let chartContainers = [];
        for ( let i=0; i<process_data.length; i++ ) {
            chartContainers.push( <ReactHighcharts config = {config}> </ReactHighcharts> )
        }

        return chartContainers;
    };


}
```

During render I get mistake:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

What can be a reason? And how can I solve it.

Comment: because you forgot `()` here: `{this.getChartItemsList()}`, call that method, voted to close the ques : 'Simple Typo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `this.getChartItemsList()`:

```
{typeof process_data == "undefined" ? " "
                    :
                    <div className="ui segment">
                        {this.getChartItemsList()}
                        <div className="ui button tiny fluid sidenav4">
                            Info
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

By the way you can do the condition with this syntax:

```
{
  process_data && (
  <div className="ui segment">
    {this.getChartItemsList()}
    <div className="ui button tiny fluid sidenav4">
      Info
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```